# How do I send emails to multiple people with different body?

Tags: python, pandas, email, outlook, pandas-groupby

I want to group recipients by reason and sent out tailored emails for each reason. The data looks like this.

```
    Email              reason
0   one@outlook.com    Address
1   two@outlook.com    Address
2   three@outlook.com  Phone Number
3   one@outlook.com    Postcode

import Pandas as pd
    data = { 'Email': ['one@outlook.com','two@outlook.com','three@outlook.com','one@outlook.com'],
           'reason': ['Address','Address', 'Phone Number','Postcode']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

This is how I started.

```
for e in df['reason'].unique():
print(f"Reason: {e}")
print(df[df['reason'] == e]['Email'].to_list())
print('\n')

Reason: Address
['one@outlook.com', 'two@outlook.com']

Reason: Phone Number
['three@outlook.com']

Reason: Postcode
['one@outlook.com']
```

Not sure how to use this list below.

```
message = "Update" 
email_subject = "Test"
recipients = e
    
# sending email function
def send_mail(text, subject, recipients):
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.to = ''
Msg.BCC = "; ".join(recipients)
    
Msg.Subject = subject
Msg.HTMLBody = text
Msg.Send()
    
# sending email
send_mail(message,email_subject,recipients)
```

How to set 3(or more) different email body's and loop around the grouped list to sent separate emails for each reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the following code in the loop:

```
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.to = recipient;    
Msg.Subject = subject
Msg.HTMLBody = text
Msg.Send()
```

where `recipient` is an email address of a single recipient.

You may find the [Using Visual Basic for Applications in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook) article helpful.